# search element in flutter by mapped field

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, mobile, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple collection of dish, for each of those I have a list of ingredients.

I want to search all dishes with particular ingredients, but if I wrote an ingredients I can retrieve more than one ingredient.
Imagine for example I have 3 dishes with Oil ingredient, but I can have different oil (Extra virgin, Peanut ...) so when I wrote OIL I have to retrieve all dish with all types of oil.

I have list of dishes where each dish is composed by:

```
dish_1-->
|       |-->name: name_1
|       |-->ingredients -->
|                         |--> 1 --> 
|                                  |-->id:1
|                                  |-->name: Extra Virgin Oil
|                         |--> 3 --> 
|                                  |-->id:3
|                                  |-->name: Pasta
|
dish_2-->
|       |-->name: name_2
|       |-->ingredients -->
|                         |--> 2 --> 
|                                  |-->id:2
|                                  |-->name: Peanut Oil
|                         |--> 3 --> 
|                                  |-->id:4
|                                  |-->name: Tomato
```

I used Model - Helper - Provider and my idea is retrieve all ingredient-ID with "Oil" from Ingredient collection and after query by those ID.
in my dish_helpers I wrote:

```
Future<List<DishModel>> searchDishByIngredient({String ingredient}) {
    String searchKey = ingredient[0].toUpperCase() + ingredient.substring(1);
    List<DishModel> dishes = [];
    return _firestore.collection(subcollection).orderBy("name").startAt([searchKey]).endAt(
        [searchKey + '\uf8ff']).get().then((result) {
  for (DocumentSnapshot ingredient in result.docs) {
        _firestore.collection(collection).where("ingredients."+ingredient.id.toString()+".id",isEqualTo: int.parse(ingredient.id) ).get().then((result) {
          for (DocumentSnapshot dish in result.docs) {
            dishes.add(DishModel.fromSnapshot(dish));
            print("Length: " + dishes.length.toString());
          }
        });
      }
      return dishes;
    });
  }
```

and in dish Provider

```
Future searchByIngredient({String ingredientName}) async {
    dishesSearched = await _dishServices.searchDishByIngredient(ingredient: ingredientName);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

When I search by ingredient, I obtain always an empty list but in console I obtain :"Length: 2".

I'm getting crazy in order to understand what I missing

Can anyone help me?

Other ways to perform search are accepted.

Thank you

Comment: You might be returning the dishes empty before you populate the List. Try to print the dishes right before you return them and tell me the result please.

Comment: I obtain 0 length, maybe is what you say, how I can solve? @lrsvmb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you return the get call to the collection and not the List itself. I would recommend writing the code like this:

```
Future<List<DishModel>> searchDishByIngredient({String ingredient}) async {
  String searchKey = ingredient[0].toUpperCase() + ingredient.substring(1);
  List<DishModel> dishes = [];

  dynamic result = await _firestore
      .collection(subcollection)
      .orderBy("name")
      .startAt([searchKey]).endAt([searchKey + '\uf8ff']).get();

  for (DocumentSnapshot ingredient in result.docs) {
    dynamic result2 = await _firestore
        .collection(collection)
        .where("ingredients." + ingredient.id.toString() + ".id",
            isEqualTo: int.parse(ingredient.id))
        .get();

    for (DocumentSnapshot dish in result2.docs) {
      dishes.add(DishModel.fromSnapshot(dish));
      print("Length: " + dishes.length.toString());
    }
  }

  return dishes;
}
```

In your code snippet the async call to get the collection would be executed and log the data as you explained it but you would not get the `List` you expect as return as it returns you the `Future` for the `get` on the collection.

Comment: It seems to work! Great, I understood the error!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are returning the dishes before you populated the List. This is because the for-loop has async calls in it (**then()**) and completes after you returned the dishes.
The solution is to simply use **Future.forEach** and await the execution of that. There is also no need to return the .then() callback, since you can just await it.

```
Future<List<DishModel>> searchDishByIngredient({String ingredient}) async {
    String searchKey = ingredient[0].toUpperCase() + ingredient.substring(1);
    List<DishModel> dishes = [];
    var result = await _firestore.collection(subcollection).orderBy("name").startAt([searchKey]).endAt([searchKey + '\uf8ff']).get();    
    await Future.forEach(result.docs, (DocumentSnapshot ingredient) {
      _firestore.collection(collection).where("ingredients." + ingredient.id.toString() + ".id",isEqualTo: int.parse(ingredient.id)).get().then((result) {
        for (DocumentSnapshot dish in result.docs) {
          dishes.add(DishModel.fromSnapshot(dish));
          print("Length: " + dishes.length.toString());
        }
      });
    });
    return dishes;
  }
```

Comment: I errors related to type of Dishes, It cant return methods of List for type Future

Comment: Since this question is already answered, I updated my answer for everyone else :)